# Iris Error - Unresolved 'Get'

Tags: go, intellij-idea, go-iris

This is my code

```
`package main 
 import "github.com/kataras/iris"
 func main()    {
     iris.Get("/hi",    func(ctx    *iris.Context)  {
         ctx.Writef("Hi %s",    "iris")
     })
     iris.Listen(":8080")
 }`
```

I have "go get -u github.com/kataras/iris/iris"
this is what i get, and i've been surving and still cannot solve this.

./IRIS.go:6: undefined: iris.Get
./IRIS.go:9: undefined: iris.Listen

This is my first time trying this framework, I followed from page https://docs.iris-go.com/
I though it would easy, but its really not, i only can do install iris, and this is my first worse hello world

I'm using Intellij Idea as my IDE

Please Help Me. Thanks

Comment: There is a hello world example in the repository: https://github.com/kataras/iris/blob/v6/_examples/examples/hello-world/main.go - although I suggest you start with a better tutorial: https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/ - which will reduce confusion later on.

Comment: hello world from golang documentation not doubt that's working, but iris documentation is not working perfectly

btw, thanks for you answer, maybe the documentation is not working again for this ages

Comment: @BudayaLanu: if you're just getting started, I would avoid iris ([I would actually avoid iris altogether if possible](http://www.florinpatan.ro/2016/10/why-you-should-not-use-iris-for-your-go.html)). Start with the basics in the std lib, and start with the std documentation: [How To Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html).

Comment: In your question you mentioned you ran `go get -u github.com/kataras/iris/iris` did you also ran `go get -u github.com/kataras/iris`? `kataras/iris` and `kataras/iris/iris` are related but not the same.. that documentation you followed seems outdated. But as @JimB already mentioned `iris` should probably be avoided for various reasons.

Comment: @mkopriva      i ran this, go get -u github.com/kataras/iris/iris i don't if they are different, thanks for you information

Answer (score 0):

It's funny because the https://github.com/kataras/iris and the https://iris-go.com and https://docs.iris-go.com have many examples of those things, you spend your time asking that, you probably checked a third-party fork of Iris and not the Iris itself where did you find that code snippet?

The correct way:

```
package main 
import "github.com/kataras/iris"
func main()    {
    app := iris.New()
    app.Get("/hi", func(ctx iris.Context)  { // go > 1.9
        ctx.Writef("Hi %s", "iris")
    })
    app.Run(iris.Addr(":8080"))
}
```

Here's another example, a simple server which renders a template file with message to the client:

```
// file: main.go
package main
import "github.com/kataras/iris"

func main() {
    app := iris.New()
    // Load all templates from the "./views" folder
    // where extension is ".html" and parse them
    // using the standard `html/template` package.
    app.RegisterView(iris.HTML("./views", ".html"))

    // Method:    GET
    // Resource:  http://localhost:8080
    app.Get("/", func(ctx iris.Context) {
        // Bind: {{.message}} with "Hello world!"
        ctx.ViewData("message", "Hello world!")
        // Render template file: ./views/hello.html
        ctx.View("hello.html")
    })

    // Method:    GET
    // Resource:  http://localhost:8080/user/42
    app.Get("/user/{id:long}", func(ctx iris.Context) {
        userID, _ := ctx.Params().GetInt64("id")
        ctx.Writef("User ID: %d", userID)
    })

    // Start the server using a network address.
    app.Run(iris.Addr(":8080"))
}
```

---

```
<!-- file: ./views/hello.html -->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{.message}}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
$ go run main.go
> Now listening on: http://localhost:8080
> Application started. Press CTRL+C to shut down.
```

If you ever need any help with Iris you can always contact with the support team via the live chat https://chat.iris-go.com. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

If Go 1.8 remains the basic host for your go apps then you should declare and use the github.com/kataras/iris/context package on your source file's imports statement.

```
package main
import (
"github.com/kataras/iris"
"github.com/kataras/iris/context"
)

func main() {
app := iris.New()
app.RegisterView(iris.HTML("./views", ".html"))

app.Get("/", func(ctx context.Context) {
    ctx.ViewData("message", "Hello world!")
    ctx.View("hello.html")
})

app.Run(iris.Addr(":8080"))
}
```